# hackerrank circular array rotation terminated due to timeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm stuck on the circular array rotation algorithm on hackerrank with timeout issues and having trouble making it more efficient.

I'm using javascript:

```
  function processData(input) {
    var arr = new Array(4);
    var arrInt = [];
    var n, k, q, index, temp;

    arr = input.split(" ", 3); //input is a string, get n,k,q from this

    arrInt = input.split("\n");

    n = parseInt(arr[0]);
    k = parseInt(arr[1]);
    q = parseInt(arr[2]);

    var arrIntI = new Array(n);

    arrIntI = arrInt[1].match(/\d+/g); //read in integer array
    arrInt.shift();
    arrInt.shift();

   for(i = 0; i < k; i++){ //rotate array k times
        arrIntI.unshift(arrIntI.pop()); //Timeout on cases: 5, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14; passes all others!!!!!!

       //********************** Manual rotation: 
       //Timeout on cases: 5, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14; Worse that Pop/unshift!!
       //temp = arrIntI[n-1];
       //for(l = n; l > 0; l--){
       //    arrIntI[l] = arrIntI[l - 1]; 
       //}
       //arrIntI[0] = temp;
       //delete arrIntI[n];
       //*******************************
    }    

    for(j = 0; j < q; j++){
        index = arrInt[j];
        console.log(arrIntI[index]);        
    }    

} 

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    _input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   processData(_input);
});
```

I tried replacing the unshift/pop to rotate the array with a for loop but it didn't help the time out cases.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to actually rotate the Array at all, you can compute everything by just playing with the indices.

```
function int(v){ return v|0 }

function processData(input) {
    //parse input string
    var rows = input.split("\n");
    var values = rows[1].split(" ");
    var [n,k,q] = rows[0].split(" ").map( int );

    //a minimal validation of the input string
    if(values.length !== n || rows.length-2 !== q) 
        throw new Error("inconsistent imput");

    //compute a positive offset
    var offset = n - k%n;       
    //the requested indices start in row 3 (index 2)
    return rows.slice(2)
        //compute the offset positions, and return the particular values
        .map(m => values[ ( int(m) + offset )%n ])
        .join("\n")
}
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I'm a bit late with explaining this.

First, imagine you have a clock (one of the classic round ones with hands on it), and you get the excersize: "rotate the numbers on the clock 5 hours to the left, and then tell me wich numbers are at positions for 1, 3 and 6 o'clock?" 

 how do you do that? Would you start dismounting the clock and then, 5 times, moving each number one position to the left?
I bet you'd not touch the numbers at all, but simply say to yourself: "rotate 5 hours to the left, then every position shows the number 5 indices to the right of the asked position", and when asked for the actual numbers at a particular index you go to index 3 for example, add 5 indices, and tell the number you read at that position.

That's how this works. I simply add the asked index and the offset, and return the value at that position.

Is it clear now, how this works?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the following is the fastest array rotater. It rotates an array by provided amount (n) and direction (+/-)

```
Array.prototype.rotate = function(n){
  var len = this.length;
  if (n % len === 0) return this.slice();
  else for (var i = 0, res = Array(this.length); i < len; i++) res[i] = this[(i + (len + n % len)) % len];
  return res;
};
```

Comment: That's probably not as fast as it could be. Doing `n %= len; if (n < 0) n += len;` at the beginning should let you simplify the indexing considerably. I'd also check whether removing the `% len` from the loop entirely would save enough time to be worth splitting the loop into two (one for `i + n < len` and the other for the rest). Also, if you're going to handle `n % len === 0` as a special case, it would be better not to create the unnecessary `res` array in that case.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen I would agree only with the last sentence "Also, if you're going to handle n % len === 0 as a special case, it would be better not to create the unnecessary res array in that case. "

Comment: the fastest version for me: `Array.prototype.rotate = function(n){
  return (n = (n>0? this.length: 0) - n % this.length)? 
    this.slice(n).concat(this.slice(0, n)): 
    this.slice();
}` and also the shortest. Let the optimizer earn it's money.

Comment: ok, my bad. This changes as soon as Arrays get just a little bigger. `Array.prototype.rotate = function(n){
  var len = this.length, i = 0, j = ((n>0? len: 0) - n % len), out = Array(len);
  while(j<len) out[i++] = this[j++];
  j=0;
  while(i<len) out[i++] = this[j++];
  return out;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
function rotation (arrData, position) {
   var newArr = arrData.slice();
   var arrLen = newArr.length;

      var num = (position < 0)
                ? arrLen-(position%arrLen)
                : position%arrLen;

      var tempArr = newArr.splice(0, num);
      newArr.push.apply(newArr, tempArr);

   return newArr;
 }
```

It will rotate according to the input

```
var a = [11,2,3,4,5];
rotation(a, 42); // [3, 4, 5, 11, 2]
```

It works pretty well in timeout cases also.

Hope this helps ! Thanks
Working example : http://jsbin.com/rahidox/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 0):

```js
function circularArrayRotation(a, k, queries) {
    let y;
    let x=[]
    
    for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        y = a.pop()
        a.unshift(y)  // no timeout issue, might be a bit longer but it works. 
    }
    

    for(let j = 0; j < queries.length; j++) {
       x.push(a[(queries[j])])
    }

    return x
}
```